# Drilled hole behind drywall and hit metal

Tags: drywall, drill, studs

I was drilling a hole upward behind my vertical drywall to get to the floor above me and I hit some metal (endoscope video of the hole here: https://streamable.com/3be9hz). What is the metal that I hit, and did I do any major damage to it?

On the other side of this vertical wall is the front of my house, which is a layer of bricks (you can see the brick at the end of the video). Also, I think I partially drilled into a stud at the end of the hole, so it could be a metal plate connected to that. Not sure.

Comment: It could be a metal protection plate doing its job, but the location seems to be more like a joist hanger/or similar.  Knowing enough to stop and ask is good, but without knowing the plumbing/electrical of the home, it will be a guess.

Comment: Okay, hopefully it's just a joist hanger. Was any serious damage done to it, or can I just let it be?

Comment: A joist hanger or a plate should be okay.  I would be worried if it is a protection and you drilled though it, but you stopped before.

Comment: It looks like air duct

Comment: Observe the aluminum tape, it is normally used on air ducts or exhausts

Answer (score 1):

I didn't watch the video... But generally speaking there are 2 types of pieces of flat metal one can find in a well constructed home.

1. joist hangers.

   - These are located at the top of walls and keep you joists up. They wouldn't be significantly damaged by accidently hitting one with a drill. There isn't a problem with putting an extra hole in one of these as far as I know... But unless you know for sure what it is
2. Protector plates.

- These are steel plates that are placed to protect wires/pipes from future home remodulation. They exist solely to be hit by drills, to prevent the wires/pipes behind them from being destroyed... Not really damaged by drills, but don't drill further.

TLDR:

If you hit a piece of metal you weren't expecting when drilling thru drywall. or somewhere else in a house. **STOP** the piece of metal means don't drill here.

Comment: could be a brick tie

Comment: You missed "air duct" if the HVAC is ducted air.